# Languages in my fantasy story

Tags: copyright, constructed-language

I'm writing a story right now, mostly because I just felt like it. At the moment I don't plan on doing anything fancy with it just keeping it to myself. I just want to make sure I won't be getting into trouble if I decide to show it to the world someday.
I want to incorporate different languages in my story. So for example humans, elves, dwarfs etc. can all speak common language but if a demon would talk to another demon they would speak in another language.

I was browsing around the net for some inspiration and stumbled upon this website right here: [Abyssal Language 5e DND](https://5elanguages.com/abyssal/). Would I be able to use this alphabet in my story or is it somehow copyrighted or should I rather create my own language like other authors do it?

Comment: It sounds like your example language is a "transliterative Alphabet" which typically have symbols that represent the letters of a native alphabet.  These are super easy to create and if you want to look sufficiently different, you can usually achieve more letters by creating symbols for common letter pairs (I tend to make the sounds "Th" "Sh" and "Ch" seperate letters, plus two different letters for "Q" which correspond to "Qu" and "Q" so I can do words like "question" and "Iraq" and typically the "Qu" sound is in place of the latin Q on my alphabet (this nets me 30 letters)+

Comment: Numbers are occasionally done, however, the arabic numbers have a design that specifically showed the value ascribed to them (while more stylized today, the 10 digits of Arabic numbers when developed each have a number of angles in the design that correspond to the value represented.  Consider 2 which originally looked like "Z".). +

Comment: You can also have your numbers in a different base, especially if your demons have a different number of digits (for example, if you have three fingers and a thumb, then they would use base 8 (four digits per hand, two hand.  Remember all count Bases start at Zero and include N-1 as a single digit where N is the base.  Base 8 would be 0-7 and 10 =8 in Base 10).+

Comment: One problem with Transliterative Alphabets is that while good for reading, it's difficult to make it sound different, as the symbols represent the same sounds.  You can see this in action if you do transliteratives of Cyrillic alphabet to the Latin Alphabet.  You haven't translated the word, you merely put it into the alphabet you understand.  For example "mir" in Russian will transliterate to the spelling of Mir in Cyrillic, but once you put it into the Latin alphabet, you still need to know "mir" is Russian for "peace".